# Gource Command Line not reconginzed command

Tags: git, github, gource

I installed Gource for git visualization and am running `gource` at the root of my git repository in `cmd`, however I am receiving the error `'gource' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: You did not have the Gource installation directory in the path.

Comment: So if my gource installation directory is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Gource`. What would be the correct command?

Comment: Did you find gource.exe or gource.com or gource.bat in this directory? If it is not there in this directory can you lookup in the bin directory?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, for instance, Gource installs to `~\AppData\Local\Gource\gource.exe`.

If you navigate to the root directory of your git repository, you can simply type:

`~\AppData\Local\Gource\gource.exe` in PowerShell.

Otherwise, you can pass a repo path as an argument following the usage description: `gource [options] [path]`.